# Netlogo error when using procedure from code example Many Regions Example procedure

Tags: netlogo

I'm new in Netlogo . I'm trying to use the code included in the Many Regions Example of the library. But I get one error in this procedure

```
 to keep-in-region [ which-region  ] 
 if region != which-region [
 let region-min-pxcor first item (which-region - 1) region-boundaries
 let region-max-pxcor last item (which-region - 1) region-boundaries
 let region-width (region-max-pxcor - region-min-pxcor) + 1
 ifelse xcor < region-min-pxcor [ 
 set xcor xcor + region-width      ]
 [if xcor > region-max-pxcor [   
 set xcor xcor - region-width
  ]
 ]
 ]
```

The error I get is .... any advices? Thanks in advance

-1 no esta mas que o iqual a cero.
error while a-seller 31 running ITEM
  called by procedure KEEP-IN-REGION
  called by procedure ADJUST
  called by procedure GO
  called by Botón 'go'

Comment: Better translate the error, not everybody here understands Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting ("-1 isn't greater than or equal to zero.", once translated to English) is caused by passing -1 as an index for the `item` primitive.

There are two lines in the code that make use of `item`:

```
let region-min-pxcor first item (which-region - 1) region-boundaries
let region-max-pxcor last item (which-region - 1) region-boundaries
```

As you can see `(which-region - 1)` is the expression passed to `item` as index. If you are getting `-1`, it must be because `which-region = 0`.

In the "Many Regions Example" model, region `0` is reserved for the patches that are not part of any regions, namely, the patches that act as region boundaries. The regions themselves are numbered from 1.

Look in your code for the place where `keep-in-region` is called and make sure that you are using a region number that is between 1 and the number of regions you have (inclusively).

Disclaimer: I originally wrote the "Many Regions" code example. Maybe I could have used a value like `nobody` for the patches outside of any region and number the actual regions starting from 0 instead of one, but I don't remember if I actively decided against it or just didn't think of it.